# How to read from a file not in Eclipse in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a file which is needed for running tests - this file needs to be personalized (name and password) by whomever is running the test. I do not want to store this file in Eclipse (since it would need to be changed by whomever runs the test; also it would be storing personal info in the repo), so I have it in my home folder (/home/conrad/ssl.properties). How can I point my program to this file?

I've tried:

```
InputStream sslConfigStream = MyClass.class
    .getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("/home/" + name + "/ssl.properties");
```

I've also tried:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream sslConfigStream = ClassLoader
    .getSystemResourceAsStream("/home/" + name + "/ssl.properties");
```

Both of these give me a RuntimeException because the `sslConfigStream` is null. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do not use the ClassLoader to load a file that is not on your classpath. Use a FileInputStream and point it to the hardcoded location of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `FileInputStream` to read data from a file.  The constructor takes a string path (or a `File` object, which encapsulates string path).

**Note 1:**  A "resource" is a file which is in the classpath (alongside your java/class files).  Since you don't want to store your file as a resource because you don't want it in your repo, `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()` is not what you want.

**Note 2:**  You should use a cross-platform way of getting a file in a home directory, as follows:

```
File homeDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
File propertiesFile = new File(homeDir, "ssl.properties");
```

Comment: Thanks! The FileInputStream worked. If I have time, I'll revisit and try your Note 2. The link shared by Visher (http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) was very helpful with understanding FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

InputStream sslConfigStream = new FileInputStream("/home/" + name + "/ssl.properties")

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your work, using Java's 7 method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "/path/to/your/file/ssl.properties";

    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                Charset.defaultCharset());
        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can also improve your way of reading properties file, using Properties class and forget about reading and parsing your .properties file:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Is this a graphics program (ie. using the Swing library)? If so it is a pretty simple task of using a JFileChooser.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

```
JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser();

int rval = f.showOpenDialog(this);

if (rval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    // Do something with file called f
}
```

Comment: It is not a graphics program. Thanks for the link though!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *Scanner* to read the file.

```
String fileContent = "";
try {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(
      new File( System.getProperty("user.home")+"/ssl.properties" ));
  while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
    fileContent += scan.nextLine();
  }
  scan.close();
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
}
```